# trying to find xpath to automate python/selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am trying to automate the fronttend website for the company I work for, but I am having problem trying to find this xpath, when I run the test case in pyhton I get the following :

```
"Selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div/lc-app/lc-auth-app/top-menu-bar/div/div[2]/top-menu-bar-right-section/div/top-menu-bar-right-section-drop/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/button/span "}"
```

********THIS is the xpath i currently have, see below please********

```
 *"/html/body/div/lc-app/lc-auth-app/top-menu-bar/div/div[2]/top-menu-bar-right-section/div/top-menu-bar-right-section-drop/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/button/span"*
```

can I find this specific xpath? I have attached the pic of what Im trying to find.. the "activity" path, I need to be specific, but I cant get it to work   [activity xpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bnia.png)

Comment: for some reason that didn't work, still getting the same error message :(

Comment: Did you try the `WebDriverWait` option? Also check if element available inside any iframe?

Comment: share the DOM file along with your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following `Xpath`.

```
//button[@class='top-menu-drop-link']/span[text()='Activity']
```

**Python code:**

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='top-menu-drop-link']/span[text()='Activity']").click()
```

However it is best practice to use `WebDriverWait` And `element_to_be_clickable`()

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@class='top-menu-drop-link']/span[text()='Activity']"))).click()
```

**Note**: To execute WebDriverWait you need to import followings.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Great answer. Always advisable to use relative XPath notation over absolute.